# os x server saves dns files on root instead of `/Library/server/named`

Tags: dns, osx-server

my attempts to activate dns-sd on my os x server installation have somehow broken where it saves dns settings! `db.[FQDN]` files are NOT going to `/Library/server/named` where they used to (and where Edit Hostname looks for them) but are being dumped right on the root folder. what file do i edit to get dns to look at the right filepath?

running os x server el capitan, newest version and fully updated as of now 6/14/16

Answer (score 0):

i found it!
in /Library/server/named/named.conf there should be a line inside options like this:

> options { 
>   directory {"Library/server/named"; 
>   };

it's there when you set up server but not when you delete all the files in 'named' and then rebuild from server.app when it's already set up.